# Angular 9: How show with a HttpInterceptor the stacktrace of a request?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have a [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) and I want for developing purpose print the stack trace of the functions that have made the request:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('Who has made this request?', new Error().stack);
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

The output of the console log is:

```
at HttpInterceptorService.intercept (:4200/main.js:1344) [angular]
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (:4200/vendor.js:30718) [angular]
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (:4200/vendor.js:31484) [angular]
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (:4200/vendor.js:30718) [angular]
    at HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (:4200/vendor.js:31549) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (:4200/vendor.js:30457) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (:4200/vendor.js:112207) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (:4200/vendor.js:112197) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.next (:4200/vendor.js:107493) [angular]
    at Observable._subscribe (:4200/vendor.js:116912) [angular]
    at Observable._trySubscribe (:4200/vendor.js:106949) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (:4200/vendor.js:106935) [angular]
    at MergeMapOperator.call (:4200/vendor.js:112182) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (:4200/vendor.js:106930) [angular]
```

The output don't show any useful information about what component or service has made the request.

There are some tips for show a useful information for find the stack trace of services and components?

Comment: Maybe you should try disabling optimization ?

Comment: Try `console.trace()` instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: Console.trace() show the same output

Comment: I doubt that it's possible with the current rxjs version. I did read that with rxjs7 the stack traces will be more readable. You could try it out, I don't know if angular works with it though :)

Comment: @PierreDuc I think this require some angular's trick, eg.: inject the stack trace into the request before start...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace inside the interceptor is already messed up. You can also think about using a custom `HttpClient`. This is untested code though. So if you remove your interceptor provider and replace it with:

```
{ provide: HttpClient, useClass: TraceHttpClient }
```

And your `TraceHttpClient` would look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class TraceHttpClient extends HttpClient {
  constructor(handler: HttpHandler) {
     super(handler);
  }

  request(...args: [ any ]): Observable<any> {
    console.trace('Who has made this request?');

    return super.request(...args);
  }
}
```

You can see a working version [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruxwvd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftrace-http-client.service.ts). You can see the stack trace having the different button method calls. You should open the browser console though, because the stackblitz console does not show the `console.trace` logs.

The `HttpClient` calls `request` for every GET/POST/etc.... So it's enough to just extend that method, and put a trace there, and delegate back to the base `HttpClient` class

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to the accepted answer. I don't want the noise of emitting a stack for every http call.

Once in the HttpClient error handler, the stack trace is lost so, `console.trace` is ineffective. `Errors` are expensive so I don't want this in production.

```
/**
 * Extended HttpClient that generates a stack trace on error when not in a production build.
 */
@Injectable()
export class TraceHttpClient extends HttpClient {
  constructor(handler: HttpHandler) {
    super(handler);
  }

  request(...args: [ any ]): Observable<any> {

    const stack = environment.production ? null : (Error()).stack;
    return super.request(...args).pipe(catchError((err) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      if(stack) console.error('Cloud UI - HTTP Client error stack\n', stack);
      return throwError(err);
    }));
  }
}
```